# Running eclipse with remote Git checkout repository

Tags: eclipse, git, putty, ssh-tunnel, sshfs

On my windows laptop, I use putty to ssh on the remote server where I have git checkout a C project. I would like to use eclipse(CDT) for program development on my laptop but compilation and program execution is only possible on the remote server. Can I map the repository checked out on remote server into eclipse on my laptop so that I can avoid working with two copies of the checked out project.

Comment: I think no, if your remote is Linux/Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

This seems not possible *unless* you are using an Eclipse installed on the remote machine... and use it on your Windows laptop.

See "[Remote Eclipse over X11](http://develorium.com/2015/05/remote-eclipse-over-x11/)".
Since you are on Windows, you would use an X11 emulator like [vcxsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/).
That would avoid the sshfs setup.

The other approach would be to replicate your remote machine environment in a VM (VirtualBox) or a Docker image/container in order to be able to compile locally (and then push the modified sources to your remote machine with Git)